# From smooth scroll to normal one and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'll start linking you the [website](http://clashnow.maxfet.net:9010/staff.html) which I'm referring to.

This [one](https://mega.nz/) instead is an Official website which has this feature already up and working, maybe you'll understand better what I mean hopefully!

I've made 2 sections, and applied a scroll that needs just a single mouse scroll to get automatically to the next section.

But in this page, I have a table in the 2nd section, a long one, so I'd prefer to disable that fixed view of the section and enable the normal scroll in order to see the whole table.

But, I'd like to be able to switch back to the other scroll when I'll scroll up til the end of the second section, ready to go back to the 1st.

This is my JS script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        css3: true,
        scrollingSpeed: 600,
        autoScrolling: true,
        fitToSection: true,
        fitToSectionDelay: 1000,
        scrollBar: false,
        easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
        easingcss3: 'ease',
        //Design
        controlArrows: true,
        verticalCentered: true,
        sectionsColor: ['#ccc', '#fff', '#cfc'],
        fixedElements: '#header, .footer',
        responsiveWidth: 0,
        responsiveHeight: 0,
    });
});
```

I am using FullPage to do this, maybe some of you already know it.

**EDIT:**

This is the `body` **setup**, 2 `section`s, `#first` and `#second`, each one inside a `div` of class `.section`, and both `div`s inside the `div` `#fullpage`:

```
    <div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="first">
        <p style="color:#fff; margin-bottom: 50px; font-size: 5em; text-align: center;">Staff</p>
    </div>


    <div class="section" id="second">


<!-- Capo -->
    <table>
    ...
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't do much more for you, this is a  **[fiddle!](https://fiddle.jshell.net/diego_carrascal/3v2zoub2/66/)**  with a hack to your problem, more than a solution, but hope it inspire you to find a much better aproach and solution

jQuery:

```
var sec=0;
$('#first').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
     console.log('scroll, '+sec+", "+$("#fullpage").scrollTop());
     if(sec == 0 && $("#fullpage").scrollTop()!=0){
        $("#first").slideUp(300,function(){
          $("#second").show(function(){
            $("#second").scrollTop(1);
          });
        });
     }
});

$('#second').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
   if(sec==0){
    sec=1;
   }
   console.log($("#second").scrollTop());
   if($("#second").scrollTop() == 0){
     sec=0;
     $("#second").hide();
     $("#first").slideDown(300, function(){
        $("#fullpage").scrollTop(0);
     });
   }
});
```

and the addition to your CSS:

```
#first{
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
  height:401px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#second{
  display:none; 
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#fullpage{
  height:400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I really love programming, but got my own software to develop and maintain ;)

Comment: Dosen't seem to work, may that be 'cause of the section Class? But if I remove it it won't autoscroll first.. what code may you find helpful? Which one should I post you?

Comment: Sorry, you got me a little confused... I don't see the "section Class" in your code, could you elaborate a little more? but then again I can't test the code I'm posting, is just the way I would start facing the problem.

Comment: I don't think so because I'm aiming to the id as a unique identifier. I assume you change the id name to yours, like so: `if($("#second").is(":visible")){...}` I update my code with it... The plugin use the class `section` or you added for CSS styling?

Comment: The plugin uses it

Comment: Very nice :) , but it seems to work... the table displays with the scroll and the upload section scrolls automatically. is the problem somewhere else?

Comment: Well in chrome I see the first part that load the files and when I scroll down it goes to section two where it change to scroll bar and allow me to scroll down... when I go un and the scroll reach the top, the automatic scroll works again and scroll to the first section. isn't it right?

Comment: It is! But it doesn't work this way to me, weird, how's that possible?

Comment: Yes it is, navigators keep some files to "speed up" navigation, so sometimes you see old versions of the scripts and pages being used...

Comment: Will try to delete cache then

Comment: Mmmmm, nope, still not working, are you on Chrome and on my website? http://clashnow.maxfet.net:9010/staff.html ?

Comment: Oh, and how to fix that in mine instead? Any ideas why that's not working?

Comment: No really, I see it uses a class `jspScrollable` and when you scroll it just change (-+)100 the `CSS top` style attribute, also when top == 0 it hides that div and shows the top one... it's a fake scroll on a `display:absolute` div, and probably control the scroll by reading the `scrollTop + div Height == window.screen.availWidth` or something like that... Hope it helps you.

Comment: Mmm what should I basically do then?

Comment: Well that's the problem with plugins they work great as long as you stick to their original functionality... What I would do in your place is create my own scroll thing... two `div` with CSS `position: absolute; top:0px; left:0px` first div `display: block;` second one `display: none;` and on event scroll down check if first div visible and second div `top >= 0` then visibility of the divs toggle... let me create some code and I come back to you...

Comment: It still very rough but i'll try to make it work better... I'm at work :D [scroll](https://fiddle.jshell.net/diego_carrascal/3v2zoub2/57/). Hope it point you in the right direction.

Comment: Cheers man :) Took a look, and yeah that's the idea, but I'm sure you're already fixing everything ahah Make sure to let me know the progresses, you ain't alone! Happy coding :D